# What is this pan called, and what is it used for?

Tags: pan

This pan was given to me recently, apparently it was with the other baking items we got from my Grandmother. It is very shallow and appears to have a no-stick coating. As you can see there's a ring around the outside as well as a depression in the center, with slanted sides.

What is this pan called, and what is it used for?

[image]

Comment: Does it separate into two parts?  If so, it's probably a pie dish with a drip catcher

Comment: Are you sure this is a pan and not a cover for a pan or pot?

Comment: It doesn't separate. It's one pan. There were, however, two of them in the box.

It doesn't seem to be a lid for anything else that I already had or that also came in the box of goodies. I also don't think it'd be a lid because it's no-stick and I've never seen a lid that had a no-stick coating. Not that it couldn't exist..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a [Holzit pie pan](https://www.google.com/search?q=holzit+pie+pan&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D18&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=Hva4UK21HsK82wW62YGAAg&biw=1010&bih=741&sei=Ifa4ULPaH-TB2QX64oGwDw), used for making berry pies, where the filling may expand and run over the side of the pie during baking.

Comment: The picture from the OP is now on that link :).

Answer (score 0):

It could be used for something like cheesecake which some recipes call for a water bath around the baking pan. So this allows you to put water around the inner pan for a water bath!

Comment: But the inside looks like it is shaped like a pie pan, not a cake pan.  Plus the water bath should the cheese cake instead of just around the perimeter.

Comment: Ouch...I can't believe I got down voted. :) I've actually seen cheesecake made in a pie tin.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like something you might put on top of your stove,  some pre made pancake only pan that you buy on tv late at night.

Comment: I couldn't make sense of your answer. Are you suggesting it is used for reheating pre-made pancakes, or keeping them warm? Have you seen these for sale via TV shopping?